# DLOOKUP Value In textbox Unable to save into table MS Access

Tags: ms-access, dlookup

After having a successful  Dlookup function,am able to autofill my two textbox, one for the combobox and the other for the text,but now,when I click save only the combobox is able to save,the textbox is not saved in the table.how can i save both by clicking save

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CF10.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7TYf.png

Comment: Need code (macro or VBA) to save calculated data to table. `Me!Cost = Me.Cost`. Really shouldn't need DLookup(). Include Cost in product combobox RowSource then can reference combobox column by its index. If Cost is in 3rd column its index is 2: `Me!Cost = Me.comboboxname.Column(2)`. Only save cost if the product cost can change over time.

Comment: kindly where should this code fall,is it in COST EVENT OR SAVE EVENT

Comment: Try the form BeforeUpdate event. ASAIK, no such things as "COST" and "SAVE" events.